# Use Generator CodeGen in Tatsu

Tags: parsing, grammar, generated, tatsu

I have generated Model code and parser from my Grammar but I can't modify model to generated code in python.
My EBNF grammar is a script code like "C" syntax for translate file in XML or ANSI X12.
It's a language specific and I would like to generate Python code from this script with Tatsu.
I parse script but I can't success to use Parser or Model to generated Python source code.... Where i must to save Model or modify parser to generated python code ... I see tools.py ... can I copy the code to build a new code model...
Can you help me ... I start learn python and i must to implement this solution on web site with upload script and download python code.

Answer (score 0):

TatSu is a parser generator. I doesn't have any provisions for generating running code from text parsed by an arbitrary grammar.

You have to write your own code generator (walk thes AST after a parse, and generate the corresponding code).

Comment: Thanks, but with ANTLR , the code generate the call JAVA and you can overwrite function for build output file (example code python...). the Tatsu Codegen/python.py can do that for a grammar ? i will do the same think with mys code "C" and grammar for writing my python code ... It's possible .. like python.py script ?